# Step in proof involving Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

I was just looking at a proof that shows how the Euler-Mascheroni constant exists and is situated between 0 and 1 . However, I stumbled across a step in the proof that doesn't seem very obvious to me .

[image]

Why is it that Hn>Integral from 1 to n+1 of 1/x dx ? Is it that obvious ?

Comment: Yes from your picture : the (positive) difference between $H_n$ and $\int_1^{n+1} \dfrac {dx}x$ is the dashed part of the picture (remember that $x\mapsto \dfrac 1x$ is decreasing over $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$).

Comment: oh...yeah, that's perfectly logical.Thanks a lot !:D